# WSO2 EMM2.2.0 emm console error

Tags: wso2-iot

I've encountered an error on the emm console when I try to login as the default admin. This happens when I replace the ip address with the domain name. Login into publisher, store and carbon works fine.

Here is the error message on the emm console page:

> HTTP Status : 500 
> {/app/modules/oauth/token-handlers.js} Could not set
>   up token pair by password grant type. Error in token retrieval -
>   setupTokenPairByPasswordGrantType(x, y)

Here are the error messages on the log:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-23 10:29:10,943] ERROR
>   {/app/modules/oauth/token-handler-utils.js} - 
>   {/app/modules/oauth/token-handler-utils.js} Error in retrieving access
>   token by password grant type - getTokenPairAndScopesBySAMLGrantType(x,
>   y, z)  
> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-23 10:29:10,944] ERROR {auth-module} -
>   An exception thrown when executing the script '/app/modules/login.js'.
>   
> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-23 10:29:10,944] ERROR {auth-module} - 
>   {/app/modules/oauth/token-handlers.js} Could not set up token pair by
>   password grant type. Error in token retrieval -
>   setupTokenPairByPasswordGrantType(x, y)

How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to resolve the error by using a reverse proxy and installing the SSL certificates.

However, I run into this error:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-02 16:06:07,734] ERROR {/app/modules/oauth/token-handler-utils.js} -  {/app/modules/oauth/token-handler-utils.js - getDynamicClientAppCredentials()} Error in retrieving dynamic client credentials. 
>   
> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-02 16:06:07,746] ERROR {auth-module} -  An exception thrown when executing the script '/app/modules/login.js'. 
>   
> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-02 16:06:07,746] ERROR {auth-module} -  {/app/modules/oauth/token-handlers.js} Could not set up encoded tenant based client credentials to session context as the server is unable to obtain dynamic client credentials - setUpEncodedTenantBasedClientAppCredentials(x)